# I am trying to parse XML from URL but it just shows me only first 3 elements not all

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse this url 
http://rssmix.com/u/8304287/rss.xml

I have tried this code which i got from a website it was working fine with their own link but when i try it on my  link it just shows me first 3 elements results. I want to parse whole XML but i don't know where the mistake is may be in for loop or something please help. Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    // Declare variables
    TextView textview;
    NodeList nodelist;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Insert image URL
    String URL = "http://rssmix.com/u/8304287/rss.xml";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate a TextView in your activity_main.xml layout
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute(URL);
    }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("Android Simple XML Parsing using DOM Tutorial");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                // Download the XML file
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
             //   doc.getDocumentElement();
                // Locate the Tag Name
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel");
                Log.v("BIGASS",doc.toString());




            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    // Set the texts into TextViews from item nodes
                    // Get the title
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Title : "
                            + getNode("title", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the description
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Description : "
                            + getNode("description", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the link
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Link : "
                            + getNode("link", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the date

                }
            }
            // Close progressbar
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // getNode function
    private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you xml there is only one channel tag as a result when you execute

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel");
```

you will get only one element.
My understanding is that you want a list of all items, for that you should do something like

```
items = channelNode.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

in your for loop.
your doPost method will look something like this

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);// This will be your channel node

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
//here call 
List<Elements> items=eElement.getElementsByTagName("item") //This is give list of all items
                    //loop over the items and parse title,description and link.

                }
            }
```

Comment: When i change it to item it  get crashed by saying i am accessing a null value.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.w3c.dom.NodeList.getLength()' on a null object reference
        at indusapps.pakistaninews.MainActivity$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:112)
        at indusapps.pakistaninews.MainActivity$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:68)

Comment: You need to call getElementsByTagName("item"); on channel node.

Comment: Can u exactly tell  me where i should call this i don't understand where is channel node sorry bit noob here in that  XML thingy.

Comment: edited the answer, please check if you understand now

Comment: The thing is what you are doing currently in almost correct, but you are doing that on channel node instead of items. So in postExecute you need to get list of all items and parse title,description and link from that

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.w3c.dom.NodeList.getLength()' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you please share the new code,  postExecute and doInbackground

Comment: I didn't do anything same code with your for  loop idk ELEMENTS so i put string there but again same error. Can you please teach me how to parse the XML from URL forget this code  as it's not working. here is my  email gmpanh@gmail.com

Comment: If you are really wan to learn, then please follow this link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp . Use the api's mentioned to parse the required nodes and elements.